# Execute a prototype function

Tags: javascript

I have a private class rs. After its definition I have the following code.

```
rs.prototype = new EventTarget();
rs.prototype.constructor = rs;
```

EventTarget defines a fire method. From within an rs method I am trying to call self.fire(..)
The call crashes with "undefined is not a function"

Within Chrome when I put the mouse over self it gives

```
__proto__: rs
```

opening that I have

```
constructor: function rs(...
```

under that is

```
prototype: EventTarget
```

under that is

```
__proto__: EventTarget
```

under that is

```
fire: function (..
```

How do I call the fire function? Is there a problem because this is a private class?

Comment: Can you give us a fiddle so that it'll be easier to track the problem?

Comment: Try to set the prototype part of inheritance with `rs.prototype = Object.create(EventTarget.prototype) ` maybe re use EventTarget constructor by rs by having `EventTarget.call(this, arguments)` in rs constructor. Constructor functions should start with an upper case so rs should be Rs. More on constructor functions and prototype here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved by moving it outside the host class, so that it was no longer private.
Not really a solution to the question.